# how do i access data from a dataframe using the column name

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have an oracle table with xml data stored in it (xmlType). I'm trying to sqoop it to hdfs with the below command. the xml field is getting displayed as null in the hdfs file.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBconnString 
             --username uname --password pwd 
             --delete-target-dir 
             --table sample 
             --map-column-java column1=String
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a sqoop limitation, the xmlType is not supported.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_data_types

There is a workaround here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2749 which is essentially convert your xmlType to clob and then map it to string using the following option

```
--map-column-java "XMLRECORD=String"
```